# Reference tools to measure propensity to cooperate and to forgive?

Tags: measurement, behavior

**QUESTION:**

Where can I find reference tools (e.g. questionnaires) to measure the psychological propensity to adopt some behaviors, such as cooperation, cheating and forgiveness?

**BACKGROUND:**

[image: Graphics from the Explorable Explanation about "The evolution of Trust"]

The 2017 "explorable explanation" https://ncase.me/trust/ is a 30mn online activity inspired by the 1984 book "[The evolution of cooperation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316766066_Robert_Axelrod%27s_1984_The_Evolution_of_Cooperation)" (260 pages) by Robert M Axelrod. It is running on desktop web browser about some principles of game theory such as zero sum game and positive sum game, and some general principles of collaboration, trust and forgiveness.  Is is unclear how much such activity changes the subjects' opinions about such basic topics.

**OBJECTIVE:**

I am wondering whether the web application measurably impacts people's propensity to collaborate and forgive errors from others, and I would like to refactor the web application so that to request the subjects to fill a questionnaire before and after (and, eventually, at the middle), in order to measure how their "values" or self-perceived propensity to collaborate, to cheat, to forgive people who seemingly cheated, and how many times. I could make up my own questionnaire, and I could measure such propensity by having the subjects simply play the game where they can cooperate or cheat, but I assume that cooperation and cheating is something which has been already studied already in Psychology. A simple online search with the terms "measure cooperation propensity" did not yield anything that I could use, so I thought I might be able to get useful pointers on stackexchange.

**MORE GENERALLY**

I wonder if there is a central repository for standard evaluation forms and which study used it, to help standardize and compare results: that would be useful in order to design, implement and evaluate other explorable explanations about other topics... Any pointer welcome!

Comment: This is an interesting question. I am not a fan of questionnaire based assessments of efficacy etc. because there is always the possibility that results can be skewed by the subjects who base their answers on what they think the assessor wants to see - conformity. I will be interested in what answers come out of this question and how they deal with any conformity issues.

Comment: I am no fan of questionaires either, and I have my own ideas about how to measure the propensity of subjects to collaborate/cheat/forgive (i.e. basically put the subject in the situation to do so and measure if they do or not, either by playing "the game" or by presenting them with text scenarii), but I am curious about which one people used in past studies of collaboration/cheating/forgiveness patterns of behaviors, in case someone invented better ones than mine!